Commutativity of a diagram involving braids
I have this diagram and I want to prove its commutativity

Let me explain what it means.
$\beta$ is a braid with $n$ strings, that is represented in $\mathbb{D} \times [0,1]$. Its uper ends are $\beta(1)=\{\beta_1(1), \dots,\beta_n(1)\} $ and $\beta(0)$ the lower ends. The braid $\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}$ is a braid with all its strings straigth  and equal to $\beta(0)$. $ X_\beta$ is the cylinder $\mathbb{D} \times [0,1] \setminus \beta$ and $X_{\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}}$  is $\mathbb{D} \times [0,1] \setminus \mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}$. $\mathbb{D}_{\beta(0)}$ is the disk minus the points $\beta_1(0), \dots, \beta_n(0)$, and the same with $\mathbb{D}_{\beta(1)}$.
The functions $i_{\beta,0/1}$ are inclusions of the disk in the base or in the top of the cylinders. $C_\beta$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{D} \times [0,1]$ to itself that maps the strings of $\beta$ into straigth strings moving the upper ends and fixes $\partial\mathbb{D} \times [0,1] \cup \mathbb{D} \times [0,1]$. $D_\beta$ is practically the same as $C_\beta$ but restricted to the top of the cylinder.
And $u_g$ is the isomorphism of grups given by $u_g([\alpha]) = [g^{-1} \alpha g]$ where $g$ is the path given by $(t) \mapsto (P,t)$. P is a basepoint in $\partial\mathbb{D}$.
$\mathbf{1}_*$ is the identity. The functions with subscrips "*" are the induced isomorphisms (all are isomorphisms).
I have proven that $\mathbb{D}_{\beta(0/1)} \times \{0/1\}$ are deformation retracts of $X_\beta$.
And I want to prove that the diagram is commutative! I know it is, and it seems very intuitive, but I cannot prove it rigorously. Specially the square in the middle.
The idea is that the path $g$ is fixed by $C_\beta$.
I have written this:
In the middle one we use that $\mathbb{D}_{\beta(0)}$ is a deformation retraction of $X_{\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}}$ and $X_\beta$. Therefore for every $[\alpha'] \in \pi_1(X_{\mathbf{1} _{\beta(0)}};(P,0))$ there exists a representative $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}_{\beta( 0)} \times \{0\}$. The same thing happens on the top cover. Furthermore $C_\beta$ is the identity in $\mathbb{D} \times \{0\} \cup \partial \mathbb{D} \times [0,1]$, so $C_\beta(g^{-1} \alpha g) = g^{-1} \alpha g$, . We deduce that $C_{\beta,*} \circ u_g ([\alpha']) = C_{\beta,*}([g^{-1} \cdot \alpha \cdot g]) = [g^{ -1} \cdot \alpha \cdot g] = u_g([\alpha']) = u_g \circ C_{\beta,*}([\alpha']) \; \forall [\alpha'] \in \pi_1(X_{\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}};(P,1))$.
Thanks to anyone reading this. I know the notation may not be the best.

You essentially have the right idea, but you don't want to start with an element of $\pi_1(X_{\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}};(P,0))$, and rather with an element of $\pi_1(X_{\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}};(P,1))$. Given an element $[\alpha]\in\pi_1(X_{\mathbf{1}_{\beta(0)}};(P,1))$, the class $C_{\beta,*}u_g[\alpha]$ is represented by the loop $C_\beta\circ(g^{-1}\cdot \alpha\cdot g)=g^{-1}\cdot (C_\beta\circ\alpha)\cdot g$, indeed because $C_\beta$ fixes $\partial\mathbb{D}\times[0,1]$. On the other hand, the class $u_gC_{\beta,*}[\alpha]$ is represented by the same loop, and therefore the middle square commutes.
The top and bottom squares commute by functoriality: we already have commutativity on the maps of (pointed) topological spaces that induce these maps. The left horizontal composite is indeed the identity, because of the deformation retract that you noticed.

Thank you  very much
